# updating a input field based on selectlist option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<select name="title" id="title">
  <option value="Mrs" >Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr" >Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss" >Miss</option>
  <option value="Dr" >Dr</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="gtitle" id="gift_title" value="" />
```

Now by default `Mrs` is shown as the first option of the select list. What I need to do then, is to get this value and display it in the `input` field. Subsequent selections by the user, i.e he/she choses `Mr`, must also update this input field as well.

I was hoping I could this in jQuery, but I wasn't sure how to get these values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe for the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and update the value of the input:

```
$(function() {
    // initialize the value of the input field to the selected value
    // of the dropdown list:
    $('#gift_title').val($('#title').val());

    $('#title').change(function() {
        // when the value of the dropdown list changes
        // update the input field
        $('#gift_title').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bXMV/).

Comment: I suggest using this.value instead of $(this).val() but they both do work

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="title" id="title">
  <option value="Mrs" >Mrs</option>
  <option value="Mr" >Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss" >Miss</option>
  <option value="Dr" >Dr</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="gtitle" id="gift_title" value="Mrs" />
```

I added default value to html

```
$('#title').change(function(){
    $('#gift_title').val(this.value);
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/JafLT/)

but I fail to see any reason for this just use the select value when you submit there should be no need for input feild

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the awnsers provided already, I suggest the following, to populate the input field with the default value of the checkbox at load.
Insert something like this between line 4 and 5 of Darin's code:

```
$('#gift_title').val($('#title').val());
```

or consider making the change callback function explicit so it could be reused.

Hope this helps!